# Error using Timer in C#

Tags: c#, methods, timer

What's wrong with my code here. Really appreciate any help. I'm trying to create a simple Scheduler class with a time object in it but I'm getting error **'timer1' does not exist in the current project**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Timers;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
class Scheduler
{
    Timer Timer1 = new Timer();

    public DateTime ShowCurrentTime
    {
        get
        {
            return DateTime.Now;
        }
    }

    public void Enable()
    {
        timer1.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer1_Elapsed);
        timer1.Interval = 5000;
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void timer1_Elapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

Comment: What as the title to do with the question?

Comment: How is the Title related to the body?

Comment: oh, damn... I didn't realize the title. Can it be changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the variable

> Timer1

defined with upper case. 
Then you access it with

> timer1

C# is case sensitive.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your timer1 declaration is wrong

```
Timer Timer1 = new Timer();
```

C# is case sensitive language :)

Comment: Lol... thanks... and that was a fast reply!! Do experts like you check this website for new questions often?

Comment: I usually look at new questions once per day. It does not occur special :)

Answer (score 1):

You are defining as `Timer1`, but using `timer1`.

C# names are case sensitive.